# Using sizeof on a typedef instead of a local variable

Tags: c++, c, typedef, sizeof, type-alias

Like in this example (in C):

```
typedef int type;

int main()
{
    char type;
    printf("sizeof(type) == %zu\n", sizeof(type)); // Outputs 1
}
```

The output is always the size of the local variable `type`.

When C++ removed the need to write `struct` before each use of a structure it still preserved the `struct {type}` syntax and introduced an alias (`class {type}`) to explicitly refer to a structure or class.

Example (in C++):

```
struct type {
    int m;
};

int main()
{
    char type;
    printf("sizeof(type) == %u\n", sizeof(type)); // Outputs 1
    printf("sizeof(struct type) == %u\n", sizeof(struct type)); // Outputs 4
    printf("sizeof(class type) == %u\n", sizeof(class type)); // Outputs 4
}
```

My question is if there is a way to explicitly refer to a `typedef` in C or C++. Something like `sizeof(typedef type)` perhaps (but that does not work).

I know that it is common practice to use different naming conventions for variables and types to avoid these kinds of situations but I would still like to know if there is a way within the langauge to do this or if there is not. :)

Comment: Your file-scope typedef and your block-scope `char` object have the same name. The fix is to rename one of them so you can refer to them unambiguously. (`type` is a poor name for a type anyway, unless it actually represents a type, e.g. in the code that implements a compiler or interpreter.)

Comment: this will not cleanly compile due to this line: char type; which becomes char int; which will either raise a alias or a masking warning.  In any case, the printf will always use the local variable 'type'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to resolve this one but if your structure is defined globally you can use this,

**Scope resolution operator** `::`.

```
printf("sizeof(type) == %zu\n", sizeof(::type));
```

Comment: @AlexFarber: Yes, I just noticed that.  So this question is completely about scope.

Comment: @Venkatesh: Yes, you can.  But not both a typedef and a variable.  However this is legal: `int main() { struct type {}; int type; }`

Answer (score 4):

In C this is not possible. You are hiding the type `type`. You cannot use it as a type after you declare the `char`:

```
typedef int type;

int main(void) {
    char type;
    type t;      // error: expected ‘;’ before ‘t'
    printf( "%d %d\n", sizeof type, sizeof t );
    return 0;
}
```

However, if you create an alias for `type` or declare a `type` before you declare the `char` you can use that:

```
int main(void) {
    type t;
    char type;
    printf( "%d %d\n", sizeof type, sizeof t );
    return 0;
}


int main(void) {
    typedef type type_t;
    char type;
    printf( "%d %d\n", sizeof type, sizeof( type_t ) );
    return 0;
}
```

C++ has the scope resolution operator `::` which you can use to reference the type using the qualified name, i.e. `::type` or `my_namespace::type`.

Comment: I accept this answer because I think it is the best answer. It tells me how to refer to a `typedef` that is overshadowed and does not rely on `type` being in global scope.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, use :: operator to get the answer as 4.

```
printf("sizeof(::type) == %u\n", sizeof(::type));
```

The :: is used for accessing global variables in C++. In C, there is no direct way i think. You can do it using functions.

The :: operator works even if it is not a class or struct.

```
typedef int type1;

int main() {
 int type1;
 cout<<sizeof(::type1);
 return 0;
}
```

This will also give the answer as 4.

Comment: There is no `struct type`.  `type` isn't a class.  Can you use the `struct` type introducer on things that aren't classes?

Comment: @jrok please read the question, for C++ code, he didnt used typedef and struct.

Comment: @BenVoigt sorry there was a typo, I updated my answer.